# Do we need to show that a function is globally one to one for change of coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, change-of-basis, change-of-variable

I was wondering, when we apply the change of coordinates for an integral, if we need to show that the transformation is globally one-to-one. If it is simply a linear transformation, if the determinant Jacobian is not 0, then it is globally one-to-one. However, if the transformation is not linear, then the Jacobian not being 0 simply shows that it is locally one-to-one.

However, do I need to show that the function is globally one-to-one, within the bounds of the integral?

Also, is there any advice on how to do this? I am not even sure how to show that something like the spherical coordinates is one to one within some bounds.

Thank you!

Comment: The way to attack this problem is by using [partitions of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity).

Comment: But my question is if I need to show that it is globally one to one. Like, if the determinant of the jacobian is nonzero in the bounds of the integral, is that not enough?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not enough. A standard example is

$f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} e^x\cos y \\ e^x\sin y \end{pmatrix}.\ f$ has non-vanishing Jacobian at all $\vec x\in \mathbb R^2$ but it is not injective.